# how to input string in istream& operator

Tags: c++

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, IntlPhoneNumberWS& obj)
{

    char nm[100];
    cout << "Subscriber   : ";
    is.getline(nm, 100); //problem
    obj.set(nm); //sets nm to current object; 
    return is;
}

void IntlPhoneNumber::set(char* nm) //only example
{
    strcpy(name,nm);
}
```

when i debug the code and come to **is.getline(nm,100)** it does not prompt me to enter anything and simply jump to next line leaving **nm as NULL**

what should i do..??

Comment: Don't output anything in the operator. Prompting should be handled outside the operator. And technically, `nm` will never be `NULL`, though it may be empty.

Comment: Oh, and you might want to check the [state](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) to make sure none of the flags are set, as well as check the [number of characters read](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount) to be on the safe side. At least for debugging.

Comment: Are you calling  like this cin>>> <IntlPhoneNumberWS&> obj;

Comment: You should also consider starting to use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: no i want the user to enter a string and store that string in the current object,but is.getline() does not prompt to enter a string...

Comment: @user2901571 see my answer below. You can't do that with istream::getline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely, you likely have a trailing newline character remaining in the input buffer from a previous operation, likely involving `operator>>` and some other variable.  `getline` is reading up to that trailing newline, which is exactly what it is looking for, and so it is not prompting for any more input.

There are various ways to handle this, but it depends upon what you consider valid input for your `IntlPhoneNumberWS` object.  For example, you might call `getline` once, and if you get an empty string, call it again.

Comment: so should is use is.ignore() to overcome this problem..??

Comment: @user2901571: If you do that, it will skip characters unconditionally, even if there is no trailing newline from a previous operation.  It seems unlikely to me that is what you actually would want to happen.  But then, I don't know what you want to actually happen.  I put a suggestion in my answer based on my *guess* of what I think you want to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong method and/or class for the job.
istream::getline extracts characters *from* the input stream and stores them into the provided char buffer. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/

Comment: He *does* want to extract characters from the input stream and store them in a buffer.  So how is it the wrong tool for the job?

Comment: Ah, I see. What threw me off was using cout in the operator definition. I assumed (wrongly?) that he was trying to get input directly from user in there using the getline(). Clearly(?) not the case here although in his question, he is saying: " it does not prompt me to enter anything and simply jump to next line". So are the characters already in the istream or not?